# Get the moment of actual end of printing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing

i'm developing an app in wpf that is printing photos in a loop, so I would like to get actual moment when the job i really done and I can proceed to another.

I'm printing using PrintDocument class, I tried EndPrint event but it is hit when file is sent to the printer, not when printer did its job. Also in system queue the document disappears before end of printing. Is it possible to get some how information of status of printer?

```
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument(); 
        PrinterSettings.PaperSizeCollection ps = pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes;
        PaperSize size = new PaperSize();
        foreach (PaperSize Psz in ps)
        {
            if (Psz.PaperName == ev.PaperSize)
            {
                size = Psz;
                break;
            }
        }
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName =  ev.printerName;
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = size;
        pd.DocumentName = "aaaaa";
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage2;
        pd.EndPrint += new PrintEventHandler(this.PrintEnd2);
        pd.Print();

        var myPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
        var pq = myPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(ev.printerName);

        var jobs = pq.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();

        foreach (var job in jobs)
        {
            var done = false;
            while (!done)
            {
                pq.Refresh();
                job.Refresh();
                done = job.IsCompleted || job.IsDeleted || job.IsPrinted;
            }   
        }

        ai++;
        PopAction();
```

Comment: `LocalPrintServer` have `IsCompleted` and `IsPrinted` properties

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work. Or works the same as EndPrint it is switched when job is sent to the printer, nothing is interrupting so the printer knows that It can print, but still it is hit before printing not by the end.

Comment: I also have checked IsPrinting property of queue in localPrintServer with same effect.

Comment: The flag isCompleted or isPrinted is never raised, only the flag isDeleted. Strange (The printer is doing its job)

Answer (score 0):

It can be find out through **PrintSystemJobInfo.IsCompleted**. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printsystemjobinfo.iscompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: As i written above, it is hit when the job is transfered to the printer.

Comment: **var pq = myPrintServer.GetPrintQueue(ev.printerName);** Using this **PrintQueue** object, you my check the **IsPrinting** flag. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.isprinting?view=netframework-4.7.2

If the flag changes to **true**, the job printing job is started and it's in progress. When changes to **false** the printing job is completed.

Comment: I've tried it as i mentioned.             while (pq.IsPrinting)            {              
            } before ai++; with same effect :(.